# Should I make the domain part of my customers' email addresses public?

Tags: security, email

I am building an application where my customers are businesses, e.g. The ACME Corporation, Joe Bloggs Plumbing, etc.  When a new user comes to my public landing page, one of the first things they will want to know is *Does an account already exist for my business?*  (I hoping to have some large customers...)

To answer this question I am going to provide a public facility that searches on business name.  The facility will auto-complete, so if the user types a few letters, they will be presented with a list of businesses that include those letters in their name.

In addition to the business name, I will also return information such as the street, suburb, post code and country.  This will help users to positively identify businesses.

Now, my question is, do you think it's a risk if I return the *domain-part* of the email address as part of the business information?  This is a high-quality piece of identity information, since a business need to confirm it's email address before its account becomes active.

**I must stress that I am not, under any circumstances, making the whole email address public.  Just the domain part.**

As a general rule, the domain name of a business is widely and publicly available.  I am hesitating because my system would allow a hacker to quickly collect dozens of domain names.  They could then prepend (guess) a standard list of popular user names and shotgun out hundreds of spam emails.

Are you aware of any other mainstream sites that would reveal lists of email domain names in this manner?  That would help in my decision making.

Comment: Sounds very questionable. You may want to consul lawyer on that... I think the fact that some company/person uses services provided by other entity is not public information. (Also probably off-topic on SO as opinion based).

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the users already know that they are customers. Therefore there is no need to telling them.

1. If the customer is a one man corporation, they will certainly know
2. If the customer is a large corporation, then there will be a manager who is responsible for this account.